# How to rewrite iterative version to Rx

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming

I'm rewriting a small project to Rx and got stuck.

The goal of the project is to create list of total records for every

1. NBA player (record collects both salary info + stats info: LeBron was paid 10 millions in total and has 35000 points scored, 3120 assists etc);
2. NBA team (record stats info about team in general: win-loss ratio): Cavs had 356-200 since the start of NBA.

So in the end we'll get 2 big records (record == csv file, a line for each player/team): 
NBA players:

- LeBron, 10e6, 35000, 3120
- Kobe, 3e6, 1020, 122

etc

NBA teams

- Cavs, 356, 200
- Warriors, 1000, 30

etc

Initially, there's an array of players and each player had an array of their salaries per year (basically LeBron played a lot of seasons and we've got an info about him: [ 10e6, 15e6, 20e6 ] and based on that info we update (a *salary* field), a `Map<Player, Info>` where Info has the fields like salary, points, assists. So we can just iterate over our players and first insert them as a key and then increment that salary field.

And then we've got an array of games -> we iterate and update `Map<Player, Info>` (points, assists fields) and then `Map<Team, WLBalance>`, where `WLBalance` is just a pair.

Now I want to switch to Rx and I've got 2 observables (one emits `<Player, Salary in some year>`, and the other emits `GameInfo`). And in the end I want to emit result records:
NBA players:

- LeBron, 10e6, 35000, 3120
- Kobe, 3e6, 1020, 122
  etc

NBA teams:

- Cavs, 356, 200
- Warriors, 1000, 30

I'd like to use `reduce` (to get a **total** salary, points, assists) func for Observables but I can't come up with some idea how to filter based on `Player` first. And then it's more about updating Value in `Map<K, V>` and not reducing values in some Observable.

**So my questions are**:

1. Beause these total records both observe and emit, which type should they be? Looks like subjects then.
2. How I can replace Map logic in Rx (so it'll be nice Rx approach)? The idea is that we don't know whether we've got a salary info about this player first and then try to update stats or we've got the stats about him first and then saw the salary, *which observable emitted the value about this player first*).

Answer (score 0):

It is still not clear what order you get the data in. However, if you simply want to reduce by player, then you can use the `groupBy()` operator to perform the mapping:

```
PlayerInfo mergeIt(PlayerInfo accumulator, PlayerInfo player) {
    accumulator.name = player.name;
    accumulator.salary += player.salary;
    accumulator.points += player.points;
    accumulator.assists += player.assists;
    return accumulator;
}

void runIt() {
    PublishSubject<PlayerInfo> pi = PublishSubject.create();
    pi.groupBy(PlayerInfo::getName)
        .flatMap(players -> players.collect(PlayerInfo::new, 
                                            ( piNew, p ) -> mergeIt( piNew, p ) ) )
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
    pi.onNext(new PlayerInfo("LeBron", 14000.0, 21, 32));
    pi.onNext(new PlayerInfo("Kobe", 12000.0, 22, 31));
    pi.onNext(new PlayerInfo("LeBron", 6000.0, 4, 14));
    pi.onCompleted();
}
```

You can then do the same for team data.